# Sort a list of objects based on another list order kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sorting

I have a model called Restrictions with the fields

```
data class Restrictions(
   val info: List<AccountInfo>,
   val displayOrder: List<Display>
)

// info field
data class AccountInfo(
   val name: String,
   val code: String,
   val target: Int
)


// Shows the targetText and a description (key, value)
data class Display(
   val key: String,
   val value: String
)


// Target appears in a Enum class
enum class Target(val target: Int, val targetText: String) {
    Target0(0, "NA"),
    Target1(1, "T1"),
    Target2(2, "T2"),
    Target5(5, "T5"),
    Target7(7, "T6");

    // Here function like getTargetByTargetText and similar...

}
```

After a http response i get a Restrictions model lets say like below

```
Restrictions(
  info {
     AccountInfo("name1", "code1", 1),
     AccountInfo("name2", "code2", 1),
     AccountInfo("name3", "code3", 1),
     AccountInfo("name4", "code4", 2),
     AccountInfo("name5", "code5", 2),
     AccountInfo("name6", "code6", 5),
     AccountInfo("name7", "code7", 5)
  },
  displayOrder {
     Display("T5", "Account blocked"),
     Display("T1", "Account closed"),
     Display("T2", "Account opened")
  }
)
```

So, what i want to do now, i to sort the info list according to the "target" field but based on the displayOrder.key field. For example the result for the above input should be

```
     AccountInfo("name6", "code6", 5),
     AccountInfo("name7", "code7", 5),
     AccountInfo("name1", "code1", 1),
     AccountInfo("name2", "code2", 1),
     AccountInfo("name3", "code3", 1),
     AccountInfo("name4", "code4", 2),
     AccountInfo("name5", "code5", 2)
```

How can i do this with Kotlin?

Comment: The [following link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-ordering.html) will help you.

Comment: In your example, `Display("T1", "Account closed")` is listed before `Display("T2", "Account opened")`. Doesn't it mean `AccountInfo("name1", "code1", 1)` should be before `AccountInfo("name5", "code5", 2)` in the output?

Comment: just fixed it...sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
val targets = Target.values().associate { it.targetText to it.target }
val displayOrder = restrictions.displayOrder.map { targets[it.key] }
val result = restrictions.info.sortedBy { displayOrder.indexOf(it.target) }
```

Try it at Kotlin Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/Bf8gffj4i

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that (assuming `displayOrder` contains valid and complete list):

```
private val targetToText = Target.values().associate { it.target to it.targetText }

// ...

val accounts: List<AccountInfo> = ...
val displayOrder: List<Display> = ...

val targetTextToPriority = displayOrder.mapIndexed { index, display -> display.key to index }.toMap()

accounts.sortedBy { info -> targetTextToPriority[targetToText[info.target]] }
```

The trick is to build a permanent map targetCode (Int) to targetText (String) and a map targetText(String) to its order in provided `Display`s list. Then you are able to compare any two `AccountInfo`s. You can improve `sortedWith` if you want to sort `AccountInfo` within same target.